# clickonce deployment

Tags: .net, clickonce

Given to following default security zones

> > Internet Zone
> >
> > Intranet Zone
> >
> > Trusted Site Zone
> >
> > My Computer Zone

Which security zone is appropiate to the following deployment locations?

1) web

2) web using ssl

3) password protected network share

4) cd-rom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Internet zone (Partial Trust)
2. Internet zone (Partial Trust)
3. Trusted Site Zone (Partial Trust)
4. My Computer Zone (Full Trust)